Nuxt: How to auto-redirect non-existing routes to different domain
We have a Vue2 SPA with base url https://example.com and migrated a part of this app to using Nuxt (with SSR) and Vue3, hosted on https://sub.example.com
After having replaced RouterLink with NuxtLink everywhere in this new project under sub.example.com we get the following error for all links that don't have a matching route (because those are the routes that should redirect to the main app under example.com):
500 No match for {"name":"faq","params":{}}

How can we configure Nuxt so that non-matching routes in the new project automatically redirect to the main app - i.e. "/faq" does not exist in the new app, but in the old app, so it should redirect to https://example.com/faq?

I think since you've split the app into two you would need to replace NuxtLink with <a>  element with href since it's not technically an in-app navigation
